# Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de '.'

Tags: sql

Se me presenta el siguiente error al correr esta setencia uso SQL 2005 pero no puedo encontrar donde esta el error, me podrian apoyar por favor.

```
Set rstResult = Ambiente.Connection.Execute( "SELECT SUM( Importe ) As `Ingreso`, flujo.concepto2 FROM flujo INNER JOIN coningre ON flujo.concepto = coningre.concepto WHERE estacion = '" & Trim(Ambiente.Estacion) & "' AND ing_eg = 'I' AND corte = 0 AND flujo.concepto2 = 'EFE' AND moneda = '" & cMoneda & "' GROUP BY flujo.concepto2"  )
```

Comment: Cuando dices SQL 2005 ¿Te refieres a SQL Server 2005? SQL es un estándar, SQL Server es un producto y su versión 2005 está obsoleta. Si no es SQL Server, indica cual motor de base de datos usas.

Comment: Otro problema es la posibilidad de inyección de SQL que es un gran problema de seguridad.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! El query parece correcto, cual es el error completo?

Comment: Por la sentencia parece que el error está en los caracteres que has puesto como alias de columna. `SELECT SUM( Importe ) As [Ingreso], flujo.concepto2 FROM flujo INNER JOIN coningre ON flujo.concepto = coningre.concepto WHERE estacion = '" & Trim(Ambiente.Estacion) & "' AND ing_eg = 'I' AND corte = 0 AND flujo.concepto2 = 'EFE' AND moneda = '" & cMoneda & "' GROUP BY flujo.concepto2"`. Por supuesto es mucho más fácil, ayudar a alguien cuando indica cual es el error explicitamente que te presenta.

Comment: @Javifer2 esos caracteres son válidos en MySQL. Por eso es importante que mencione el producto.

Comment: @LuisCazares Pero dice Sql 2005. Aunque el OP no haya puesto la etiqueta. Y es un comentario a su pregunta, no una respuesta. Si bien tú primer comentario puede ser adecuado, y conforme al funcionamiento del sitio, para muchos usuarios nuevos, puede ser muy agresiva. (es posible que no puedan hacer lo que les pides, porque lo desconocen). Además se pueden sentir acongojados, por los mismos, donde no se les aporta ningún valor. Y esta pregunta terminará cerrada, porque no aporta nada al sitio, ya que es un error de sintaxis.

Comment: @LuisCazares, además si haces una búsqueda por internet de la cadena `Sql 2005`, en mi caso, las primeras 8 páginas de resultados, se refieren única y exclusivamente a SQL SERVER 2005. Y aunque es posible que el motor me devuelva resultados "viciados", por mis historial, yo nunca he visto algo tan aplastante.

Comment: El motor es sql server 2005

Comment: este es el error completo que me envia : CORTEZ 14:02:27 -2147217900:Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de '`'. in line 73     Error de sistema: -2147217900 Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de '`'.

Comment: y la linea 73 es la que pegue arriba

Comment: Como es un error de sintaxis, la aproximación más fácil es eliminar todo el predicado del where e ir añadiendo según vaya funcionando. `Set rstResult = Ambiente.Connection.Execute( "SELECT SUM( Importe ) As `Ingreso`, flujo.concepto2 FROM flujo INNER JOIN coningre ON flujo.concepto = coningre.concepto GROUP BY flujo.concepto2"  )`. Si esto te funciona. Añades en la posición donde estaba, `WHERE estacion = '" & Trim(Ambiente.Estacion) & "'`....Otra opción, es usar el SQL Server profiler, para capturar la consulta explicita que estás enviando.